# Call constructor in multiple derived classes

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, super

What's the right syntax for calling the base constructors of multiple derived classes in `python3`?

```
class A:
    def __init__():
        print("A")

class B:
    def __init__():
        print("B")

class C(A,B):
    def __init__():
        super().__init__() # ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the `super` call in the parent classes too. I think how it works is `C`'s `super` gets `A` and `A`'s `super` get's `B`

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("A")

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("B")

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Or use this alternative, more explicit syntax which I prefer

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("A")

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("B")

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)
```

This calls the `__init__` methods of the `A` and `B` classes on an object of the `C` class.

Comment: It's not so much a question of what you prefer. You have to use super() if you write mixin-classes, as you don't know what classes to call. But you *can't* use super in many cases, such as if you have different parameters to the functions in different classes. So quite often your hand is forced, and you have no choice. :-)